# Curl:Unknown SSL protocol error gcm

Tags: php, android, ssl, curl, google-cloud-messaging

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Y5Y4.png)I have designed gcm server in php(MAMP). curl version-7.43.0,php version 7.0.0 .The code for server-

```
<?php



function send_push_notification($registration_id,$message){
    define('API_KEY','AIzaSyAoFih8qEFlOis3vVWhsxxlLxxxxxxxxxx');
    $url='https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields=array(
        'registration_id'=>$registration_id,
        'data'=>$message,
        );
    $headers=array(
        'Authorization:key='.API_KEY,
        'Content-Type:application/json'
        );

    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);



  $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
 }



?>
<?php
send_push_notification("e2DgrsZPGKU:APA91bF_73a6-o5CLV-gdcZzYFAbtikJqi-5w6gDSCaRa4z8-1iGLeV5SS6hQkW8pj_g_DxBe7JLDsOPMGu3y1GkKw1vpn_ZEWIeCwbSITpd0pLwaz50W8uzHKNghvnf1xxxxxxxxxxx","hi");
?>
```

When I try running this php script in my browser it shows following error

> Curl failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to
>   gcm-http.googleapis.com:443

I have disabled SSL verification,still it shows curl error.

Comment: It's not a peer name or cert issue but a protocol error.  What if you remove `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` and let cURL choose?  TLS is better (more secure) anyway.

Comment: I added `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);` after reading one of answers on this website.It makes no difference after removing it.Still the same error.

Comment: Typically there is no reason to set the SSL version - let the server and client choose the best protocol & cipher.  Adding this might help: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('php://output', 'w+'));`  It should print additional debug output from cURL, maybe shedding more detail on the protocol error.

Comment: It might be [this](https://curl.haxx.se/mail/tracker-2015-02/0008.html) bug/issue.  Verbose output might show more relevant and helpful messages, but the last one `unknown ssl protocol error` is what you see as a result of SSLv3 or TLS and RC4 (both of which GCM supports).

Comment: The above code prints no additional error message.Also there is no error in php_error.log .The browser just displays Curl failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to gcm-http.googleapis.com:443. every time I try to run it.

Comment: If possible try running from the command line.  `php://output` should output to the same buffer as print/echo but sometimes doesn't work.  Or you can try writing it to a file: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_STDERR, fopen('/tmp/debug.txt', 'a+');`  This will show verbose output from curl, hopefully sufficient detail into what is failing

Comment: The debug.txt shows following                                                             `Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 0.0.10.40...
* Connected to gcm-http.googleapis.com (127.0.0.1) port 443 (#0)
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH
* Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to gcm-http.googleapis.com:443 
* Closing connection 0`

Comment: Does it really say `Connected to gcm-http.googleapis.com (127.0.0.1)`?  That seems odd.  Here's what I get: http://pastebin.com/QGHfR2W7

Comment: Take a look at [link](http://pastebin.com/z9FgWFzK) And I am using MAMP behind a proxy.

Comment: Ahh, I would bet the proxy is the problem - best guess is the proxy isn't speaking SSL properly.  You might need to use `CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL` or use other curl proxy options to have it try to speak directly to the proxy instead of happening at the level it is now.

Comment: But I am using Proxifier(Tunneling).It shows connections being made.Look for image edit i  beginning of question(4th line in it)

Comment: What cURL & PHP version do you have?  Also, would it be possible to disablie Proxifier and try directly, or use an alternate proxy, like run [Tor](https://torproject.org) and use it's SOCKS proxy?

Comment: I added proxy settings to curl and ran the script.This time new error was encountered.`Curl failed: Received HTTP code 403 from proxy after CONNECT`.[Report](http://pastebin.com/pE1BW7AB)

Comment: That means the credentials for the proxy were invalid or missing.  Try `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, 'user:pass');` replacing user and pass with the proxy credentials.

Comment: Added credentials.Back to `Curl failed: Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to gcm-http.googleapis.com:443`.[Report](http://pastebin.com/zdqj5ayy) .

Comment: curl version 7.43.0 and php version 7.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Changing SSL version to 6 worked for me.

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,6);
```